# ¿Cómo puedo descartar archivos temporales de los eventos de watchdog python?

Tags: python

Estoy usando esta herramienta para subir mis archivos modificados a la nube, cada vez que el usuario realiza un cambio en una ruta especifica "mi nube local" ya sea que cree un archivo o lo modifique detecto el evento y subo a mi carpeta en la nube el documento o archivo modificado, con la finalidad de tener un respaldo y tener los archivos disponibles.

watchdog me regresa todos los eventos pero he notado que con los archivos de office me manda todos los temporales y aparte al realizar la indexación de la ruta me los marca como si el usuario los hubiera modificado.

la solución utilizada hasta el momento es solo cachar los eventos de modificación `event.event_type == 'modified'`
después verifico que en el path no exista este símbolo "~" y ".tmp"
para descartar directorios indexados uso

```
try: 
    os.rename(event.src_path, event.src_path)
except OSError:  
    if(event.is_directory):
      pint('es directorio')
    else:
     print('no es directorio')
```

Comment: y el problema/duda es?

Comment: Tal como lo describes debería funcionar sin problemas. En todo caso, existe una forma de ignorar patrones ya incluida: [Ignoring Files with WatchDog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24782951/13636459), podrías poner la extensión de archivos temporales o `~`